# Access CamelContext in Cucumber via Spring

Tags: spring, groovy, apache-camel, cucumber-jvm

I want to test my Apache Camel routes, which are wired together in Spring, with Cucumber.

My Test looks something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@TestExecutionListeners([DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class])
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ["/cucumber.xml"])
Class TestEnvironment {
    public TestEnvironment(){
        @Autowired
        ProducerTemplate superTemplate
        //more foo
    }

World() {
    new TestEnvironment()
}

Before() {}

Given(~/I want to send a Message "([^"]+)" to my "([^"]+)" Camel Route./) { String greatMessageString, String endpointURI ->
    MockEndpoint fakeEndpoint = getMockEndpoint(endpointURI)
    fakeEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1)

    superTemplate.sendBody(fakeEndpoint, greatMessageString) //always 'cannot invoke sendBody() on null object' 
}
```

superTemplate never links to any of my Camel routes. So I tried to extend the TestEnvironment with CamelSpringTestSupport.

```
Class TestEnvironment extends CamelSpringTestSupport {
    protected AbstactXmlApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(["/cucumber.xml"])
    }
```

The template() method is normally available as ProducerTemplate when extending the class with CamelSpringTestSupport. But it does not pick up the CamelContext for my routes either. template is always null. So is the context for the TestEnvironment.

I feel like I'm pretty close already but lack a certain annotation or whatever... Would be thankful for new input.
Cheers

Comment: I have the same issue with template being null so whenever I send it does not start the camel routes. I would really like to merge cucumber and camel together.

Comment: solved the problem. please have a look here: https://github.com/NeovaHealth/ARNIE